# android vitual device manager

Tags: android

To run my android applications on eclipse  . I am creating a new android vitual device AVD and  while creating AVD there is an option of choosing the DEVICE name. It has various options like Galaxy nexus, nexus one, nexus s ,nexus 4 ,nexus 7.. etc. Each option has its dimensions. Which DEVICE should i select to run my applications.

Comment: You are missing tons of details.  What OS are you on, what version of Android.  What have you tried.  Give a more detailed question to get responses.

Comment: It's better to provide the scenario in which you got error and some snippet of code that shows your effort.